# IF !DEBUG block works when debug is true on ASP.NET Webform project

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, webforms, release

I have a ASP.NET 4.5 WebForm project where I need to avoid do run specific functions while on the local computer.

To do this I'm using

```
#if !DEBUG
 My code
#endif
```

The problem is that this code will run any way? I have tried set the drop down combo in Visual Studio till Debug and I have tried to set the `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">` but the code is still running?

I believe that when the project is set in correct state the if section should be dimmed but it is not?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not clear but I suggest you to use property HttpContect.Current.Request.IsLocal instead.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy the question is, how do I explude specific code when running at my local computer? I have tried if debug according to my post but that does nothing? Request.IsLocal, how would it know if it is executing on my computer or the host server? I need it to run the code only at the host and not at my dev computer.

Comment: If you request the page/code from another machine than this request is not local.

Comment: Your WebForms project must/should be an `Application` for that to work. Hth...

Comment: Is this a web site "project" (File->New Web Site), or a web application project (File->New Project)? The latter will have a .csproj or .vbproj file in it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders this webpage have .sln, .suo files and thats it.

Comment: Then this is a web site "project" and it doesn't build, so I wouldn't expect DEBUG or RELEASE flags to work.

Comment: Specified code doesn't require a project. I've tested it and it works like expected on a local IIS. It doesn't run when debug is "true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important is that you remember to switch your project to `release` or `debug`. This tells the compiler which directive code block to run.

Your Syntax is correct though, you can do this as well:

```
#if DEBUG
 Some Code
#else
 My code
#endif
```